# Remote desktop via Vnc is black, mouse/keyboard works

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04. I enabled remote desktop in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Remote desktop* -> *Enable legacy VNC protocol*.
When connecting using Remmina to this machine, the session starts.
The mouse moves and the keyboard sends keys, but the screen is black.

How to configure this remote desktop and VNC client?

- When connecting Remmina 1.4.25 installed on Ubuntu 22.04 to local host, the screen works.
- When connecting Remmina 1.4.11 installed on Raspbian to Ubuntu 22.04, the screen is black.
- When connecting Remmina 1.4.25 installed on Ubuntu 22.04 to Raspbian, and then from Raspbian to Ubuntu, the screen works.

Comment: Strange, from unknown reason remote desktop works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the picture quality from the VNC client that you are connection from to something other than automatic. This is what fixed it for me.

You could also try this:

edit the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file, uncomment WaylandEnable=false, and reboot in order to remotely access the login screen.

Comment: Thank for the pointers. Not used, because from unknown reason remote desktop works now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Screen Share Not working in Ubuntu 22.04 (In all platforms VNC, zoom, teams, google meet, anydesk, etc.,)

#### How to enable/disable Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04 step-by-step instructions

#### To check which display system your Ubuntu is using, please enter this command

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

#### If the above command below mentioned output, your system is using Wayland.

wayland

#### In order to use screen sharing, we have to disable Wayland and enable Xorg (x11). To do this, Please edit to below file

sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

#### Uncomment this below line.

WaylandEnable=false

#### Restart the UI service for the immediate effect of the above changes.

sudo systemctl restart gdm3

#### Voila! You can share your screen. You can confirm this by re-entering this command.

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

#### If the above command below mentioned output, your system is using x11.

x11

#### After this follow the attached screenshot instruction

[Step -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68eD4.png)

[Step -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9YwW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these instructions which worked after I also changed my RealVNC Viewer's  Properties->Picture quality  from "Automatic" to "High"